# i want to get all field but without same name in sql

Tags: sql

Hi I want to get all field
for example

```
select * from Stock where MemberId=3430
```

without same name value but I need Id

```
select distinct name,id,MemberId where MemberId=3430
```

Id is unique so distinct is not working correctly for me

Result is like

```
Id Name
1, Stock1
2, Stock2
3, Stock2
4, Stock1
```

It doesn't work because id is unique

Comment: Please add two sample data, one the current results, and the other what results you actually want here.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: So what is the result you expect?

Comment: i am expecting
```
Id Name
1, Stock1
2, Stock2
```
i don't want to get same name row

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't specify the flavor of SQL that you're using. I've produced an answer for you that works in Postgres, SQL Server, and MySQL.

To be clear, my understanding of what you're looking for is the ability to return 1 record for "Stock2" with both of the id's associated with that value, rather than 2 separate records. To do this you need some sort of string aggregation capability. Here are three examples that will produce results you are looking for:

Postgres - dbfiddle link - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWoFG13QYyi52Vww5HxoDi/1

```
SELECT array_agg(id), name
from sample
group by name;

SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ','), name
from sample
group by name
```

MySQL

```
SELECT group_concat(id), name
from sample
group by name
```

SQL Server - sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/111ba7/4/0

```
SELECT string_agg(id, ','), name
from sample
group by name;
```